# Java how to force a programmer that use a object to specify a specific property name with a value?

Tags: java, methods

How do I force a programmer that use my class to implement a specific named property with a value, in the same way we can force programmer to implementt a interface or abstract method.

```
//DAO dao = new DAO(); 
//instansiate a transfer object Transfer trans = new Transfer();
//must set and name the propety "id" with a value to work trans.setProperty("id", "23");
//Transfer test = dao.getDataByID("23");
//System.out.println(test.getProperty("id"));
```

Comment: By threatening him *real hard* that he'll have to code in Perl for his life if he doesn't comply!

Ok, joke aside: what would you use it for? You could only access it through reflection, making it uneasy, and slow without runtime code generation...

Comment: ... by forcing them to implement an interface. Can you show some code as to what you mean and why you need them to implement it

Comment: @clcto I don't see how an interface would make it mandatory to have a given field in a class...

Comment: I have a Transfer object that has an hashmap that holds dynamic properties for this object. and i want the programmer that use this object to implement the id property

Comment: You should check the map and throw an exception if something was iffy...

Comment: I don't understand the use case.

Comment: @clcto I think there is no use case for this at all. Just curious...

Comment: So every object that has a `Transfer` must have an `Id`? Why? What do you do with this?

Comment: You should not use the word "implement" with the word property. It's confusing. You implement a behavior/method, not a property/field.

Comment: @BheshGurung maybe he came from C# where you do implement properties.

Comment: @clcto OP means that the `Map<String, Object>` in the `Transfer` object **must** have a key `"id"` with a value... (at least I think)

Comment: Thanks for waking us up on a lazy Friday afternoon :)

Comment: @ppeterka so have a `Map<String, ProvidesID>` with `interface ProvidesID{ void setId( String ); String getId(); }`

Comment: @clcto If I understand correctly, one `Map` should only have one `"id"` entry, not each value one. OP wants to have flexible objects, with runtime specifiable properties. He uses a `Map<String, Object>` to fulfill this, and would like to have some "designated" keys, like "id" to be mandatory - which I think can be only solved by explicitly checking it...

Comment: I'm confused, and give up guessing as to what he wants. @perikzzon if you update the question to show the use case or why you want to do this, it would be very beneficial to all of us speculating what you want.

Comment: DAO dao = new DAO();
        //instansiate a transfer object
        Transfer trans = new Transfer();
        //must set and name the propety "id" with a value to work
        trans.setProperty("id", "23");

Comment: Transfer test = dao.getDataByID("23");
        System.out.println(test.getProperty("id"));
        System.out.println(test.getProperty("name"));
        System.out.println(test.getProperty("lastname"));

Comment: @perikzzon see how quick you get answers if you provide useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Don't provide default constructor. Eg. -

Consider following class -

```
class User{

 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

 public User(String firstName, String lastName){
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
 }

}
```

In the above example by not providing default constructor `User()`, the programmer using User class will be forced to set firstName and lastName while creating User object.

Edit -

To address the situation where the programmer passes null value, you can check the value and throw an exception to handle that.

Comment: Calling `new User( null, null )` would be the same thing as having a default constructor.

Comment: You can test the value and throw and exception.

Comment: I think the OP wants the value to be checked by the compiler, which is not possible.

Comment: OP is confusing. I think I should delete my answer

Comment: undeleting after seeing OPs explanation :)

Comment: wow, good job. I had no idea this is what he needed initially.

Answer (score 1):

```
// TODO code application logic here DAO dao = new DAO(); 
//instansiate a transfer object Transfer trans = new Transfer();
//must set and name the propety "id" with a value to work trans.setProperty("id", "23");
```

As @hellboy's answer stated, make the constructor of `Transfer()` take an `Object` (or `string` possibly) and set it in the constructor:

```
public Transfer( Object id )
{
    this.setProperty( "id", id );
}

// or if the ID should be a string:
public Transfer( String id )
{
    this.setProperty( "id", id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is specifically tagged with the `magic` tag...

Use reflection to assert that fields exist:

```
public static boolean hasField(Object instance, String fieldName) {
    try {
        instance.getClass().getField("");
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your code

```
if (!hasField(trans, "id")) {
    // throw an exception or whatever - your choice what to do
}
```

Comment: thanks everyone forced the programmer to set the id property through the constructor. Than check in the setProperty method if the id property is in the hashmap or not